# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars from data file

Tags: python, numpy

My Code:

```
 f=open('question5.txt','w')
 i=1
 while i <= 10:
      f.write(str(i)+"\n")
      i = i+1
 f.close()

 from numpy import loadtxt

 a = loadtxt("question5.txt",int)

 from math import sqrt

 mean = sum(sqrt(a))/len(a)
 square = mean**2

 print("Root-Mean-Square: "+str(square))
```

It creates the data file correctly with:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

The error I get is:

```
 line 15, in <module> mean=sum(sqrt(a))/len(a)
 TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

After some research, I feel like I kind of get what the error means, but I have no idea how to correct this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is with `sqrt(a)`, because `a` is an array type, and `sqrt` is expecting a [Python scalar type](https://jpt-pynotes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scalar-types.html). A quick way to solving this error is creating a new list through a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), which is just a fancy, condensed way of doing for loops:

```
a2 = [ sqrt(x) for x in a ]
```

This is a new list of the square roots of each value. This is at least how I am interpreting what you are trying to do.

Now, adjust your mean line to this:

```
mean = sum(a2)/len(a2)
```

And you should be all set.

Comment: Or use `numpy.sqrt` which can work with the numpy array produced by `loadtxt`